# after clicking submit button it should redirect to another cms page

Tags: php, cms, contact-us

visit this link,

http://hotwheelstoys.in/one/em0113-full-package/index.php/contacts/index/

if you click on " submit" button , it will give you a message in the contact us page only.

we are using this code in :http://pastebin.com/U86VDhd3

i want to to display this message in the other page....

means if we click on "submit" button, it should redirect to another cms page.....

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314872/redirect-to-a-particular-page-after-contact-form-is-submitted-in-magento

Comment: can you please inform what code changes i have to do to work for my code

Comment: Go to make sure u copy to local folder should not edit core file app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php  Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');---> here add ur page url

Comment: @Manojkothari post your comment as answer......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure u copy to local folder should not edit core file

Go to-->
`app\code\core\Mage\Contacts\controllers\IndexController.php`

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('‌​Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.')); $this->_redirect('*/*/');---> here add ur page url
```